# numpy.dot answers not consistent for large vectors

Tags: numpy, matrix-multiplication

`numpy.dot` gives me inconsistent answers for large matrices.

```
mat1 = np.random.random(100000)
mat2 = np.random.random((2,100000))

for i in range(20):
    print(np.dot(mat1,mat2.T))
```

In Windows, I get the same answer for all loops but on Ubuntu 16.04 (Anaconda python 3.5) I get several different answers. This is very annoying. Can someone help me please!

Comment: Just tested with anaconda Python 3.5.4, 16.04.2 LTS, x86_64 platform and obtain equal values for all loop iterations.

Comment: No issue here on Anaconda Python 3.5.2 on Lubuntu 16.04

Comment: I updated numpy and the problem is solved. I'm not sure what caused the problem. In case anyone encounter the same problem, just update numpy.